# HTML/CSS Responsive buttons with icons

Tags: html, css

currently learning how to develop HTML/CSS websites and I'm struggling to find resources that could help me dev a practice project that I'm doing.

Could anyone teach me how to dev something like this through CSS.

[Button Samle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYlSR.png)

A button with circular icons/image for mobile. I need to make the image/icon circular and fit the button but when I just use this, the whole button resizes to the image size.

```
<button class="btn"><img src=""></img> Home</button>
```

And hopefully someone could also help with with the CSS in order to make it something like this on mobile. A menu of buttons that 2 of the buttons take up the whole size of the screen.

[Button List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upVsL.png)

Comment: W3schools has a good section on CSS that might help.

Comment: What css have you tried? It sounds like you want to target the image and give it border-radius of 50% and give it the height and width you want it to be. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_rounded_images.asp

Answer (score 2):

For learning CSS and HTML i don't suggest you to start creating elements like this button because your button is not useful in websites, like its not flat or material its something basic and after days of learning css you can make it.
anyway i suggest you to do front-end of this page its much useful for you!
and almost every basic ui developer uses this [page](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d3/fd/ec/d3fdecb6c6fc9d65c495e31a2fb34dfe.jpg).
I love teaching code's so if you're really interested i can help you in every time you stuck on this project. :)
btw i created your button take a look hope you like it. :)

```css
.btn {
padding: 13px 0;
background-color: #fff;
border:1px solid #707070;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
max-width: 229px;
position: relative;
cursor:pointer;

}

.txt {
font-size: 23px;
color: #707070;
font-weight: 500;
margin-right: 40px;

}

.btn:focus {
outline: 0;

}

.icon {
width: 43px;
height: 43px;
background-color: #fffbc6;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid #707070;
position: absolute;
top:4px;
left: 9px;

}
```

```html
<button class="btn"><div class="icon"></div><span class="txt">Button</span></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this neat button, used font-awesome icons, and bootstrap themed btns

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.875rem 1rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #248afd;
  border-color: #248afd;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0276f8;
  border-color: #0270ec;
}
.btn i {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-text">
<i class="fa fa-upload "></i>
    Upload
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look w3schools tutorials.

- For HTML : https://www.w3schools.com/html/
- For CSS : [https://www.w3schools.com/css/](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

I highly recommend you look Bootstrap 4 to build responsive pages.

- For Bootstrap4 : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{
 display:table;
 width:100px;
 text-align:left;
 padding:2px;
}

button > img {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-right:10px;
 }
```

```html
<button><img src="https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.png" width="20px" height= "20px">Home</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

w3schools is a great resource for the basics of css and html

basically you change the style of the button :on hover

The hover style sets the image for the button to be different.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp